# is there any jquery plugin to create a mosaic background?

Tags: jquery, gallery, mosaic

im looking for a jquery plugin to be able to achieve this effect

http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/1213/26201311246pm.png

i found this one, but has to be buy, im looking for a Free alternative

http://codecanyon.net/item/photomosaic/full_screen_preview/232406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery Masonry for this. http://masonry.desandro.com/

OR

Try a CSS alternative: http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any plugin for that just find a mosaic image, infact u can cut a piece from that image in the link that u shared. Then use this css and u will get mosaic background

```
body
{
    background-image:url("Your images url..");
}
```

after this it will repeat your image piece and background will be mosaic :)